# Roomba - TurtleBot1 serial communication for TeleOP

Tags: ros, roomba, roomba-500-series, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I have a roomba version 521 and I would like to use it as base of a "turtle Bot". I know this is kind of old stuff cause no one uses these base es anymore. Many use kobuki or directly start with TurtleBot version 3.

Nevertheless I would like to use a roomba version 521 as the base staion of my turtlebot. Now I am searching for software to connect this base station via a Mini - DIN serial port connector to a laptop on which ros indigo 14.04 LTS is running on.

My Problem is I do not find any **working software for communicating**  with ros with my laptop to the roomba.
I ended up with this tutorial: [wikiRobots/RoombaRobin](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/RoombaRobin).

When I tried to test the software I downloaded within this tutorial. And I started:

```
roslaunch roomba_robin_bringup minimal.launch
```

I got the following errors:

```
roslaunch roomba_robin_bringup minimal.launch ...
logging to /home/markus/.ros/log/65038936-b274-11e6-8df8-9cb70de7f81a/roslaunch-turtleBot1-6333.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

while processing /home/markus/catkin_ws/src/roomba_robin/roomba_robin_bringup/launch/includes/mobile_base.launch.xml:
while processing /home/markus/catkin_ws/src/roomba_robin/roomba_robin_bringup/launch/includes/kobuki/mobile_base.launch.xml:

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
u'/home/markus/catkin_ws/src/roomba_robin/roomba_robin_bringup/launch/includes/kobuki/mobile_base.launch.xml'
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

By the way if I connect my serial cable with the laptop and type lsusb I see the following:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

Hope if somebody knows where there is still software for the roomba 521 available?

***WIth the Tipp of Jacob:***
Thanks Jacob,

I saw that you have one of the biggest libraries for the Roombas and I already testet it...
I followed your tutorial on your Page step by step but I came into some problems when executing

> roslaunch ca_driver create_1.launch [publish_tf:=true]
>
> markus@turtleBot1:~/create_ws/create_autonomy/ca_driver/launch$
> > catkin build
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Profile:                     default
> > Extending:             [env]
> > /opt/ros/indigo Workspace:            
> > /home/markus/create_ws
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Source Space:       [exists]
> > /home/markus/create_ws/src Log Space: 
> > [exists] /home/markus/create_ws/logs
> > Build Space:        [exists]
> > /home/markus/create_ws/build Devel
> > Space:        [exists]
> > /home/markus/create_ws/devel Install
> > Space:      [unused]
> > /home/markus/create_ws/install
> > DESTDIR:            [unused] None
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Devel Space Layout:          linked
> > Install Space Layout:        None
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Additional CMake Args:       None
> > Additional Make Args:        None
> > Additional catkin Make Args: None
> > Internal Make Job Server:    True
> > Cache Job Environments:      False
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Whitelisted Packages:        None
> > Blacklisted Packages:        None
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- Workspace configuration appears valid.
> > ----------------------------------------------------------- [build] No packages were found in the
> > source space
> > '/home/markus/create_ws/src' [build]
> > No packages to be built. [build]
> > Package table is up to date.          
> > [build] Summary: All 0 packages
> > succeeded!                            
> > [build]   Ignored:   None.            
> > [build]   Warnings:  None.            
> > [build]   Abandoned: None.            
> > [build]   Failed:    None.            
> > [build] Runtime: 0.3 seconds total.   
> > markus@turtleBot1:~/create_ws/create_autonomy/ca_driver/launch$
> roslaunch ca_driver create_2.launch
> [desc:=true] [publish_tf:=true]
> [create_2.launch] is neither a launch
> file in package [ca_driver] nor is
> [ca_driver] a launch file name The
> traceback for the exception was
> written to the log file

> markus@turtleBot1:~/create_ws/create_autonomy/ca_driver/launch$
> roslaunch ca_driver create_1.launch
> [publish_tf:=true] [create_1.launch]
> is neither a launch file in package
> [ca_driver] nor is [ca_driver] a
> launch file name The traceback for the
> exception was written to the log file

**create_1.launch  is neither a launch file in package [ca_driver] nor is [ca_driver] a launch file name**

Do I have to modify the installation in some why have I installed something wrong

Best
Markus

Best
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248776/roomba---turtlebot1-serial-communication-for-teleop/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Markus,

You could check out my driver [create_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy) for controlling the Roomba base as a replacement to roomba_robin. The `create_1.launch` file should do the trick.

Jacob

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-11-25**:
as comments are not allowed to be that long I just posted an answer above ... Would be glad if you could help me.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-11-25**:
catkin is not detecting any packages. Is the create_autonomy repository actually cloned inside `catkin_ws/src` ?
Also, the square brackets `[publish_tf:=true]` are to indicate it is optional, meaning you shouldn't actual type those. You can just run `roslaunch ca_driver create_1.launch`.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-11-29**:
Hm I fixed that issue now. However I get a new Problem when executing> **roslaunch ca_driver create_1.launch**
It says the following>
Unable to contact my own server at [http://130.83.118.240:32925/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-11-29**:
After solving this error I would like to know how do I use:
rostopic pub power_led  std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray 1 2
the above code is not workin what do I have to change

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-11-30**:
You might find `rosrun rqt_publisher rqt_publisher` easier to use. I'm not sure of the proper command line syntax.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-11-30**:
As far as network issues go, I would ask around other threads. See http://answers.ros.org/question/236444/unable-to-contact-my-own-server/?answer=236592#post-id-236592

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-11-30**:
The command line syntax is:

```
rostopic pub -1 /set_ascii std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray '{data:[34,35]}'

rostopic pub /power_led std_msgs/UInt8Multiray '{data:[90]}'
```